# Custom attachment permalink structure

Tags: permalinks, attachments

I have 10 images attached to each of a custom post type. My permalink structure for the custom post type is: example.com/post-type/post-title

I am using the Wordpress Attachments plugin.

My attachment permalinks look like this example.com/?attachment_id=55

What I would like to do for the attachment permalinks is: example.com/post-type/post-title/1

How could I go about doing this?

Comment: you want your example.com/?attachment_id=55 to become example.com/post-type/post-title/55 ? P.S. keep in mind you can not make 1 from attachment id 55. Also what that attachment plugin does? from your question i see that it does nothing at all.

Comment: @Tom The question is more than a year old - could you please a) delete it or b) add the necessary info (plugin link, etc.) so it's answerable? Thanks.